# Python "run" and "reload" not showing the changes to my code

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a simple question. I am in the process of debugging some code. I am using Enthought Python, with the "PyLab" program. I edit my code using gEdit. I am using Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS.

I use "run myfile.py" to run the program. Then I test myfile(somearguments), and see where the bugs are.

However, when I make changes to the code, using "run myfile.py" again does not properly update what Python/PyLab on the changes to my code. The result is that I will get error messages back pointing to lines that have no errors, and don't even have the "trouble" text in them anymore. I tried using import and reload as well, but that didn't work.

How do I get Python/PyLab to see the new changes to my code? The only option I have for now is to fix the bug and then restart PyLab to confirm the fix.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove the pyc file ?

It may happen as the pyc file exists that PyLab keeps reading it without reloading the file.